# link(URI) to emacs org mode section

Tags: org-mode

Instead of links in org mode to external applications, what I want is links to org mode sections. I hope that open `emacs://org/id/<uuid>` in a browser will open emacs(GUI) and jump to the heading whose uuid is `<uuid>`. Obsidian has a plugin named advanced URL, open `obsidian://advanced-uri?vault=<your-vault>&filepath=my-file&heading=Goal` will open my-file.md and jump to the heading whose name is Goal. Is there a way to do the same thing in emacs org mode?

My platform is macos 10.15.

Comment: I reckon the solution could be OS specific, So you'd better state your OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at [org-protocol](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/org-protocol.html).

Here is an example of how to add your own protocol from [org-roam](https://github.com/org-roam/org-roam/blob/main/extensions/org-roam-protocol.el#L153-L170), with this we can open roam nodes with `org-protocol://roam-node?node=uuid"`

```lisp
(defun org-roam-protocol-open-node (info)
  "This handler simply opens the file with emacsclient.
INFO is a plist containing additional information passed by the protocol URL.
It should contain the FILE key, pointing to the path of the file to open.
  Example protocol string:
org-protocol://roam-node?node=uuid"
  (when-let ((node (plist-get info :node)))
    (raise-frame)
    (org-roam-node-visit (org-roam-populate (org-roam-node-create :id node)) nil 'force))
  nil)

(push '("org-roam-node"  :protocol "roam-node"   :function org-roam-protocol-open-node)
      org-protocol-protocol-alist)
```